# Assigning signs to the elements of one array that are complements of another array's signs

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider two square arrays, `a` and `b`, having the same shape.  For this example, `a` and `b` each have 6 rows and 6 columns.  Each row and each column of both `a` and `b` holds the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

In `a`, some of the elements were made negative, as shown, as part of an earlier process (the number of '-' elements isn't important).  In `b`, ALL the elements are still '+'.

```
a = np.array([[-1, -3, -5, -6,  4,  2],
              [-2, -4,  6,  5,  3, -1],
              [ 5, -6,  1,  3, -2, -4],
              [ 6, -2, -4, -1,  5,  3],
              [ 4,  5, -3, -2,  1, -6],
              [ 3, -1,  2,  4,  6, -5]])   

b = np.array([[ 4,  3,  1,  5,  6,  2],
              [ 5,  4,  2,  3,  1,  6],
              [ 3,  6,  5,  2,  4,  1],
              [ 1,  2,  4,  6,  5,  3],
              [ 2,  1,  6,  4,  3,  5],
              [ 6,  5,  3,  1,  2,  4]])
```

I need to assign signs to the elements of `b` that are the **complement** of the signs of the corresponding elements in `a`.
ie: in the 1st column of `a`, 1 and 2 are **negative**, and 3 to 6 are **positive**.
So, in the 1st column of 'b', 1 and 2 must stay **positive**, and 3 to 6 must be made **negative**.   This approach is repeated for each corresponding column of `a` and `b`.  The final outcome would look like:

```
b = np.array([[-4,  3, -1, -5, -6, -2],
              [-5,  4, -2, -3, -1,  6],
              [-3,  6,  5,  2, -4,  1],
              [ 1,  2,  4,  6, -5, -3],
              [ 2,  1, -6, -4, -3,  5],
              [-6, -5,  3,  1,  2,  4]])
```

QUESTION:  Is there an efficient way to assign signs to `b` in this way?  (the actual arrays are larger and there is a very large number of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each absolute 1-6 number is present exactly once in each column.

You can sort the columns by absolute value, copy the sign, then reverse the sorting to the original state.

Using [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), [`take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html), and [`sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
# sorter for a by absolute value
idxa = np.argsort(abs(a), axis=0)
# reverse sorter from sorted to order in b
idxb = np.argsort(np.argsort(b, axis=0), axis=0)

# sort a, reorder it like b, copy sign
out = (b*
       np.take_along_axis(
        -np.sign(np.take_along_axis(a, idxa, axis=0)),
        idxb, axis=0)
       )
```

Output:

```
array([[-4,  3, -1, -5, -6, -2],
       [-5,  4, -2, -3, -1,  6],
       [-3,  6,  5,  2, -4,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  4,  6, -5, -3],
       [ 2,  1, -6, -4, -3,  5],
       [-6, -5,  3,  1,  2,  4]])
```

Comment: Thank you, Mozway.     I had much of the sorting completed, but the  'take_along_axis'  was new to me.  Nice solution.